# Where i should put the code for checking user/pass, at the very top or not?

Tags: php, security, authorization

Currently i check user/pass in line 4 while the previous lines contain include php file for config and connecting to database and also a file that contain useful functions...

I wanna know is this wrong to check for Authority after include those file or it's better to put it at top ?

- Also i'm new in php

> require_once('includes/config.php');
>   require_once('includes/connection.php');
>   require_once('includes/functions.php');
>   checkAuthority();

PS: checkAuthority function has session_start() within it, while it's not at the top right now but still works.

Comment: I think you will need to improve your question a little to make it more salient. Try to ask a direct question, post code examples.

Comment: It still works because you havenot started out put in those included files

Comment: place an echo "hi"; statement in one of those files and you will see the difference

Comment: @TheMongMan yes there will be no problem at all until you are not starting output in those files there is not any rule that says session_start() must be at first line .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not wrong unless you are doing something in your included files that should only be done when a user is logged in. It looks though, that you include scripts that are nescessary to authenticate the user (e.g. a database connection).

Also, no one says, `session_start()` must be executed before anything else is. There must not be any other output though before you execute `session_start()` (e.g. an `echo`). If you would echo something in config.php for example, `session_start()` in `checkAuthority()` would fail.

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate user, you will need your database. For that it looks like you'll need

`require_once('includes/config.php');`

`require_once('includes/connection.php');`

Then to use the checkAuthority function, you'll need `require_once('includes/functions.php');`

So your placement is correct. There is no need to change anything.

Answer (score -1):

You probably using databases and i thing you have places those db settings in config.php so you must check user/pass after including some common files.

Comment: -1 This does not answer any part of the question asked in its current state!